# Setting a event to an object in an array c#

Tags: c#

(Wording might be terrible in the title)

I have an array of labels, I want to add mouse enter, and leave events on those labels.

This labels are created programmatically:

```
            Label [] lblData = new Label[255];
        int calcLoc = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i <= 200; i++)
        {
            calcLoc = 25 * i;
            lblData[i] = new Label();
            lblData[i].Location = new Point(10, calcLoc);
            lblData[i].Text = "Test " + i;
            InfoPanel.Controls.Add(lblData[i]);

        }
```

What I've tried:
Setting the event in the loop (obviously wasn't going to work)

```
lblData[i].MouseEnter += (sender, e) => {lblData[i].BackColor = Color.LightBlue;};
```

Setting the event before the loop (figured this might have a chance)

```
lblData[].MouseEnter += (sender, e) => {lblData[].BackColor = Color.LightBlue;};
```

Neither work.

Comment: Why "obviously wasn't going to work"??

Comment: Is this WindowsForm or WPF?

Comment: I imagine each one is taking the reference to i, so gets the last value of i. Right? You could either take a local copy of i within the loop (e.g. `var j = i;`) or declare a method to handle the event, and unbox `sender` back to the label object.

Comment: as a side note .. instead of creating 255 controls and event handlers, you can probably use single control and single event handler. For example, ListBox or DataGridView can be made to look like labels by changing color and other properties.

Comment: @Slai I did add code for a single event handler for all controls.  Can't speak to sheer number of controls, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a single method and the `sender` parameter.  Here's code with minimal changes.  You could have a standalone static method instead for all events and just check `sender`.

```
lblData[i].MouseEnter += (sender, e) => {((Label)sender).BackColor = Color.LightBlue;};
```

Safer, and slightly faster version, that all `Label` instances can subscribe to below.

Static methods are better for performance for reasons I won't go into, you avoid using closures, and this ensures the event was fired by a `Label`.

```
private static void label_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   var label = sender as Label;
   if (label == null)
      return;
   label.BackColor = Color.LightBlue;
}
```

Comment: Please comment on down votes so I can address any issues.

Comment: Of all the advise, this solution worked best for my, hence the marked as correct. Running through I had no issues and worked a bit faster then I was expecting. Thanks for the help!

Comment: No problem.  I did note performance will improve slightly.  Do remember to either dispose of the controls or unsubscribe from the event to prevent a possible memory leak.

Answer (score 3):

How about this?

```
Label[] lblData = new Label[255];
int calcLoc = 0;
for (int i = 0; i <= 200; i++)
{
    calcLoc = 25 * i;
    Label label = new Label();
    label.Location = new Point(10, calcLoc);
    label.Text = "Test " + i;
    label.MouseEnter += (sender, e) =>
    {
        label.BackColor = Color.LightBlue;
    };
    InfoPanel.Controls.Add(label);
    lblData[i] = label;
}
```

Or even this:

```
Label[] lblData =
    Enumerable
        .Range(0, 201)
        .Select(i =>
        {
            var calcLoc = 25 * i;
            Label label = new Label();
            label.Location = new Point(10, calcLoc);
            label.Text = "Test " + i;
            label.MouseEnter += (sender, e) =>
            {
                label.BackColor = Color.LightBlue;
            };
            InfoPanel.Controls.Add(label);
            return label;
        })
        .ToArray();
```